# merge sort index out of bounds java

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

Hey I am working on a merge sort method that keeps getting an index out of bound error. I can't figure out why or where that's happening. i've tried printing out the indices and seeing if there was something wrong in the recursion but I don't think there is it is pretty straight forward.

```
public ArrayList<String> mergeSort(ArrayList<String> words,int first, int last){

    if (first < last){
        int mid = (first+ last)/2;
        mergeSort(words,first,mid);
        mergeSort(words,mid+1,last);
        merge(words, first, mid, last);
    }
    return words;

}
public ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> words, int first, int mid, int last){
    int first1 = first;
    int last1 = mid;
    int first2 = mid+1;
    int last2 = last;
    int total = first1;
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((first1<=last) && (first2 <= last2)){
        if (words.get(first1).compareTo(words.get(first2))<=0){
            temp.add(total,words.get(first1));
            first1++;
        }
        else{
            temp.add(total,words.get(first2));
            first2++;
        }
        total++;
    }
        while(first1 <= words.size()){
            temp.add(total,words.get(first1));// exception occurs here
        first1++;
        total++;
        }
        while (first2 <= last2){
            temp.add(total,words.get(first2));
            first2++;
            total++;
        }
    for (total = first; total <= last; ++total){
        words.set(total,temp.get(total));
    }
    System.out.println(words);
    return words;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the exception? It tells you where...

Comment: Please mark a line where error occures

Comment: Its telling me line 50

Comment: How can we know what is line 50 on your machine? You have to explain which of the lines you've posted is line 50!

Comment: I've changed the annotation of the exception line to a comment, because the `->` wasn't very helpful in that it was making the Java invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the lines like this:

```
temp.set(total,words.get(first1));
```

You're doing this on an `ArrayList` that has no elements in it. When you call `.set()`, you have to pass it an index of an element that's already in the array (i.e., `total<temp.size()`).

I think you want two temporary lists, and you want to use `ArrayList.add()` rather than `ArrayList.set()` to put the contents of the left half into the first one, and the right half into the second one. Then you can merge them back into the original `ArrayList` (and here, you really can use `words.set()`, because it already has elements in it, just in the wrong order).

Comment: I changed the sets to add and i'm still getting out of bounds but now its at line 61 after you've exited the first while loop.

Comment: @user3400512 Yes, I'd pointed out why you were getting that error on that line, but you need to rework the code to get to a full solution. As I say, you need two temporary lists, one for each half of the array, so that you can then merge them back in.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use `set()` on an empty temp list. `set()` replaces an element in the array, but the array is empty: no element to replace.

What you need to do is `add()` into the temp list instead of using `set()`. The elements will be added sequentially, so in the right order and you do not need the `total` variable for that.

Now, it will get a little different when you replace back the elements in words. The temp list will have elements indexed from `0` to `(last - first)`, and you want to replace in words the elements from `first` to `last`. For that, I think the following loop will work:

```
for (String word : temp) {
    words.set(first++, word);
}
```

Note: because you know in advance the final size of temp (i.e. `last - first + 1`), you should preallocate it using:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(last - first + 1);
```

Comment: I implemented the loop and i still get the index out of bound exception in the same place

Comment: I see that you have edited your program to replace set(index,object) by add(index,object). However, you use the wrong version of add(). You need to use add(object) to add at the end of the list, not as a specific index that does not exist, as you start with an empty temp list

Comment: And you can also remove your "total" variable. It is not needed as all